# Individual table cost reduces, overall query cost increases

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-indexes, database-optimization

I'm trying to optimize a huge MySQL database, while doing that I'm looking into adding indexes to the table columns. Here I am noticing a strange behavior, when I add the index to the particular column, the query plan image generated from workbench shows it is reducing the cost from the particular table. But eventually it got increased in the nested loops.

Before adding the index:

[image]

After adding the index, the query plan image is this,
[image]

If you see this images in the first image, the table `W` is going through the full index scan and the query cost is 189482.4 and the number of rows fetched is 852.06K rows, I added the composite index on columns `W` and `MType` in WHERE condition. So the cost and rows returned reduced to 99815.75 and 426.03K rows respectively.

When the cost and rows returned from table `W` reduces, it should eventually reduces the cost in the nested loop right? But It is increasing.

Any explanation on this would be greatly helpful and much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4BTxtm6uvNbhjYokikvveb/0) to table create statements.

Explain result:
[image]

SELECT Query:

- Before putting values - https://pastebin.com/BfSZik7X
- After putting values - https://pastebin.com/9SN7HmMR

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, the `SELECT` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  (I am used to `EXPLAIN`, but not those pictures; they provide the same, _approximate_, data, I think.)

Comment: @RickJames Hey Rick, I've updated the question with the details you have asked. Can you please check now? Thanks

Comment: I don't see the `SELECT`, itself.

Comment: @RickJames I'm terribly sorry to miss the `SELECT` queries. I've added them in the above links. Thanks :)

Comment: OK, the `SELECT`, with its `(NULL IS NULL OR (foo = x)) AND ...` is clever, but it is clumsy to read and slow to compile.  I recommend that you build the query in your application.

Comment: Could the `LEFT JOINs` be plain `JOINs`?  (This might give the optimizer more latitude.)

Comment: The `JOIN`...`GROUP BY` is what I call inflate-deflate.  It is a common trap people get into that slows down queries.  Perhaps by building the query dynamically, you can avoid the `JOINs` in some cases?

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for your inputs. I'll look into possible ways of building the query dynamically